# Search for groups of cells that contain values, calculate the difference, place result in adjacent column

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Not sure how to approach this problem. I have a column (column A) with a list of times. The column has a lot of inconsistencies such that not all rows contain numerical values.

What I need to do is calculate the difference between the times (rows) that do contain numerical values. And I need the place result adjacent (column B) to the first value of that specific grouping of rows.

The attached photo paints a better picture explaining what I need to do.
[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWBZF.png)

There is no pattern to the data. So I need excel to search the column, find the groupings, subtract the first value from last value in a group of times, and place the result in column B.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Please next time provide the input data in [table markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) format. It helps us to reproduce the scenario, and it helps you to get more attention and to avoid negative votes. Just copy your excel data, then generate it and copy it back again to your question, leaving a blank line from previous text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may appear to overuse Excel's [let function](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-much-benefit-does-excels-new-let-function-offer-steven-rider/), but it can improve performance considerably by minimizing the calculations needed.

Throw this in cell `B4` and drag down and it should give you what you want.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A4),IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(A3)),LET(
    aColumn,A:A,
    lastUsedRow,MATCH(2,1/(aColumn<>""),1),
    CleanRange,INDEX(aColumn,ROW(),1):INDEX(aColumn,lastUsedRow,1),
    endRow,IFERROR(MIN(FILTER(ROW(CleanRange),IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(CleanRange)),ROW(CleanRange)>ROW(),FALSE)))-1,lastUsedRow),
    INDEX(aColumn, endRow,1)-INDEX(aColumn,ROW(),1)),""),"")
```

You could also improve this by having a named Range of `lastUsedRow`, `=MATCH(2,1/($A:$A<>""),1)` in the worksheet and then removing that line in the formula so it doesn't have to keep recalculating it.

Comment: pgSystemTester, Thanks for both of your suggestions. The first suggestion worked seamlessly! The data that I am using this for is close to 200k rows. Excel seems to like this solution best as it doesn't get tied up thinking/calculating. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @pgSystemTester I was testing the array formula (second), for the following input: `={"";9;6;1;"";8}` and it returns: `-1`and `0` the last value is correct, but the first one should. be `-8`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here an array version, that spills the entire result and it doesn't require an additional helper column (*formula 1*):

```
=LET(A,A2:A14,n,ROWS(A),seq,SEQUENCE(n),
 cnts,SCAN(0,A,LAMBDA(ac,x, IF(ISNUMBER(x), ac+1,0))),
 start,FILTER(seq,1 - ISNA(XMATCH(cnts,1))),
 end,IFERROR(VSTACK(DROP(start,1) - 1,n),n),
 MAP(seq, LAMBDA(i, LET(s, XLOOKUP(i,start, start),
  IF(ISNA(s), "", LET(e, XLOOKUP(i,start, end),
   f, FILTER(A, (seq>=s) * (seq<=e) * ISNUMBER(A)),TAKE(f,-1) - TAKE(f,1)))))))
```

Here a shorter alternative:

```
=LET(A,A2:A14, n, ROWS(A), seq, SEQUENCE(n), isNum, ISNUMBER(A),
 MAP(seq, (isNum=TRUE) * (VSTACK(FALSE, DROP(isNum,-1))=FALSE), LAMBDA(i,first,
  IF(first=0, "", LET(f, FILTER(HSTACK(A,isNum), seq>=i),
   last,IFERROR(XMATCH(FALSE,INDEX(f,,2))-1,ROWS(f)),
   INDEX(f,last,1)-INDEX(f,1,1))))))
```

In the above formula the second `MAP` input argument identifies the start of the group (`first`). The condition checks when the current element is a number and the previous one is not.

even shorter (similar idea):

```
=LET(A,A2:A14, n, ROWS(A), seq, SEQUENCE(n), isNum, ISNUMBER(A),
 prev, VSTACK(FALSE, DROP(isNum,-1)),next, VSTACK(DROP(isNum,1), FALSE),
 start,(isNum=TRUE) * (prev=FALSE), end,(isNum=TRUE) * (next=FALSE),
 MAP(IF(start=1,seq,0), LAMBDA(i, IF(i=0,"",
  INDEX(A, XMATCH(1,N(seq>=i) * end)) - INDEX(A,i)))))
```

Here it the output:
[image: output]

*formula 1*: First we count (`cnts`) the element on each group (numeric values) via `SCAN` (actually we only need to identify the start of the group, ie. `1` values). The name `start`, has the starting positions of each group. The name `end`, the corresponding ending positions for each `start` value. The `IFERROR` condition, considers the case there is only one group, so the end of the interval is `n` (last index position of the input array)

Now we iterate over all index positions (`i`) of the input (`seq`) via `MAP`. For each `i`-value we check if the value belongs to the `start` positions, if not it returns an empty string. Otherwise, we obtain the start and end of the corresponding interval (`s`,`e`) for a given iteration. Now we filter the input data `A` via `FILTER` to just get the numeric values from the selected interval, then via `TAKE` we get the last and the first one to do the subtraction.

Comment: Thank you for the solution David! This did exactly what I needed to do all within one column. I don't think I could have ever come to this solution on my own. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Nice. Somewhere my array formula got lost. I'm going to compare to yours. Also, thanks for making me look *normal* with all the Let functions!